# [__NSArrayM synchronize]: unrecognized selector exception

Tags: iphone, exception, nsmutablearray

I used some NSMutableArray with UIImageView objects.

When I quit the app I get this exception message:

> [__NSArrayM synchronize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b3a910

In AppDelagate.m

```
NSMutableArray * aViewArray;
...
currentView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:displayImageNamed]];
[aViewArray addObject:currentView];
[currentView release];
```

In ViewController.m

```
UIImageView *myImage = [aViewArray objectAtIndex:i];
myImage.xxx = yyy ;
```

Comment: Where are you initializing the array?

Comment: the problem is not the array. The problem is that the object which should respond to synchronize is deallocated. NSUserDefault objects would respond to synchronize. So first check for NSUserDefault objects. Or enable NSZombies to speed this process up.

Comment: Ok I use NSUserDefault to get current language :

Comment: NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSArray *languages = [defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
 curLang = [NSMutableString stringWithString: [languages objectAtIndex:0]];
 [curLang appendString: @"_"];
 
 [languages release];
 [defaults release];

Answer (score 5):

Looking at your comment regarding NSUserDefaults, you should not be releasing both `languages` and `defaults` since you don't have ownership (you didn't alloc/init them). Try removing those two calls to release and see if that resolves your issue.